# Call function inside worker thread nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here's my worker:

```
const Worker = require('worker_threads');
const worker = new Worker("function hello () { console.log('hello world');}", { eval: true })
worker.hello() // not correct
```

I would like to call `hello()`

How do I do this?

Comment: If you look at [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_worker_threads), you'll see that's not how they require `Worker`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Threads communicate through passing messages back and forth, for instance:

```
worker.postMessage("say hello");
```

Your worker would set up a listener for the `message` event, and receive the message as the `value` property of that eevnt:

```
// In the worker
const { isMainThread, parentPort } = require('worker_threads');
if (!isMainThread) {
    parentPort.on("message", e => {
        // Dispatch here. For instance:
        if (e.value === "say hello") {
            hello();
        }
    };
}
function hello() { /*...*/ }
```

There's a lot more to messaging back and forth, details in [the worker documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [worker-messenger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/worker-messenger) on npm to write that style:

```js
import { Worker } from 'worker_threads'
import { ParentMessenger } from 'worker-messenger'
const test = async () => {
    const results = await messenger.callWorker('testFunction_2', 'args', timeout)
    console.log({results});
}
test()
```