# How to run function in different thread with node.js

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, multithreading, worker-thread

I have a REST API coded with Node.js and there is one route that applies NTFS Rights to folders. The request can take 1 second but can also last several minutes (it depends on the size of the folder).

To summarize, if the rights take less than 5 seconds to be applied, I want to return the status code 200.

If the rights have not finished being applied, I would like to return the status code 202.

For that I use `Promise.race`:

```
return Promise.race([applyRights(), sleep(5)]
    .then(result => {
        statusCode = 200;
        if (result === undefined) {
            statusCode = 202;
         }
    });
```

My problem is that the function `applyRights` performs quite complex operations. Including writes to the Windows File System and applying NTFS rights with a C++ library.

It's look like the C++ function to applies NTFS rights is ***blocking the event loop***.
That means that my function `sleep` is only executed after `applyRights` is done.

Is there an easy way to run the C++ function in another thread or something like this to let the job continue in background without blocking the event loop ?

Or do I need to update the C++ library ? (what I would like to avoid doing)

Comment: You could try a [worker thread](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) or a [process](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html)

Comment: Yes I already read the documentation of worker thread but it's look like it works with file. And I was wondering if there is an easier way to create a thread. Like in C#

Comment: I don't understand how this could be any easier. Either start a JavaScript script in worker thread or a C++ program in a new process. It's one line of code.

Comment: I gave you the wrong link in the first comment. It's [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

Comment: So can you gave me an example ? Actually this line is blocking my event loop: `currentPermissionsManager.applyRights()`. How can I start this function in a new process with one line of code ?

Comment: Now I understand. You want to write the code for the main thread and the worker thread in the same file. You could start a worker thread using this script and distinguish main thread and worker thread with an `if` condition. Yes, you are right. This could be easier. I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: I'm not trying to start a script but to call a function from a npm package writted in C++

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call function inside worker thread nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60998358/call-function-inside-worker-thread-nodejs)

Comment: AFAIK, you can either start a script in a worker thread or a program in a new process. You can't run some code in a new thread or process with Node.js.

Comment: In cases like this you can NAN: https://github.com/nodejs/nan We have come across this issue too where the main thread blocks execution of our app, so we use that library to solve similar issue